# I have trouble passing an array from main to a specific function

Tags: arrays

I have a problem passing a value from `main()` to the function `method()`.
I have the variable “selected” and it's being populated in other function called `version()`; `selected` is a two dimensional matrix. I then assign these values to one dimensional matrix called `check`:

```
check[1]=selected[1][1]
check[2]=selected[1][2]
.
.
.
check[190]=selected[19][10].
```

Then I need to use the vector “check” in the function `method()` , and that's my problem... I cannot pass it correctly...

```
int main()
{
  double **selected;
  version(&selected);

  double *check;
  check=dvector(n*T);

  for(v=1;v<=n;v++) {
    for(t=1;t<=T;t++){
       check[v]=selected[v][t];
    }
  }

  method(check);

}

void version(selected)
double ***selected;
{
  *selected=dmatrix(n,T,1,1);
   .
   .
   .
  for(v=1;v<=n;v++) {
    for(t=1;t<=T;t++){
      (*selected)[v][t]=xd[v][point[v][t]];
    }
  }
}

void method(check)
double *check;
{

  for(v=1;v<=n;v++) {
    for(t=1;t<=T;t++){
      printf("check[%u]=%f\n",v,check[v]);
    }
  }
}
```

I appreciate any feedback you may have!

Comment: what language is this? I don't think it will compile(or interpret) in any language I know.

Comment: You're overwriting check[v] T times.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev Sorry, I forgot to mention! It is a c language. And you are right, this does not compile, since I am not showing the complete code, I thought this might be enough information to demonstrate my problem.

Comment: @QuentinUK Thanks for your feedback, do you mean I am overwriting in the function method()?

Answer (score 0):

```
  check=dvector(n*T);

  for(v=1;v<=n;v++) {
    for(t=1;t<=T;t++){
       check[v]=selected[v][t];
    }
  }
```

Here check has length n*T but later v is from 1 to n so only the first n elements of check get a value, all the others are undefined. For zero offset arrays the v would be correctly replaced by v*T+t, but here with offsets of 1 it is (v-1)*T+(t-1)+1:-

```
       check[v*T-T+t]=selected[v][t];
```

Answer (score 0):

When you pass an array to function there is no need to give `&`. Array is always passed as reference.
`marsversions(selected);`